# How to get the id of the value when using auto complete AJAX in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Can I get only id of the value in autocomplete search in Laravel? The current situation is like I am getting the value of employer name, but I want to get the id of employer name, so I can save it to another table in the database without saving of the employer name.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function index2(){
    return view('autocomplete.index');
}

public function autoComplete2(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->get('term','');

    $products=Employer::where('employer_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

    $data=array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
         $data[]=array('value'=>$product->employer_name,'id'=>$product->id);
    }
    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
}
```

Here is my view:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'calllogs.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}

  <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Company Recommend ') !!}
    <input class="typeahead form-control" value="" type="text" name="searchajax" id="search_text">
  </div>

  {!! Form::submit(__('Create'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
    $("#search_text").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,

    });
});
</script>
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you can't set the employer's id here `$data[]=array('value'=>$product->employer_name,'id'=>$product->id);`?

Comment: nono , i want to use post method and save only id without saving the employer name again

Comment: I hope you are using jquery UI autocomplete. so you want employee id instead of employee name when you clicked the autocomplete list right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to laravel but for Jquery UI.jqueryUI autocomplete has a option call 'select' and it trigger after clicked on a autocomplete list item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
    $("#search_text").autocomplete({
        select: function (event, ui) {//trigger when you click on the autocomplete item
            event.preventDefault();//you can prevent the default event
            alert( ui.item.id);//employee id
            alert( ui.item.value);//employee name

        },
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,

    });
});
```